# Custom onChange for React Hook Form and watch()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hook-form

I am trying to write a custom `onChange` and `watch` the change.

**Error**:

The watched `myValue` does not register the changes in the dropdown. Any ideas why?

According to the [API documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register/), this is possible by doing the following:

```
export default function App() {
  const { register, watch } = useForm();

  const fruits = register("fruits");

  const myValue = watch("fruits", "default");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{myValue}</h1>
      <select
        onChange={(e) => {
          fruits.onChange(e); // react hook form onChange
          console.log("Here would go the my onChange"); // my onChange
        }}
        onBlur={fruits.onBlur}
        ref={fruits.ref}
      >
        <option value="1Banana">Banana</option>
        <option value="1Kiwi">Kiwi</option>
        <option value="1Mango">Mango</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You may find the upper example here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-rgb-mwiqn?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not passing the `name` prop to your `select`. The documentation is saying you should be doing this by default:

```
<select {...register('fruits')}>
```

If you log what `register('fruits')` return you'll see a `name` prop in there besides `onChange`, `onBlur` and `ref`. If you add `name={fruits.name}` to your `select` you'll see `watch` working too.

Edit: yes, this is missing from the documentation too at the moment.

Comment: My guy. You are a wizard :) Yeap this is missing from the Documentation.
This is the type of the Register: `export declare type UseFormRegisterReturn = {
    onChange: ChangeHandler;
    onBlur: ChangeHandler;
    ref: RefCallBack;
    name: InternalFieldName;
};`

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to pass `register()` props to Component. By passing `{...fruits}` on select, it is working.

```
export default function App() {
  const { register, watch } = useForm();

  const fruits = register("fruits");

  const myValue = watch("fruits", "default");

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{myValue}</h1>
      <select
        onChange={(e) => {
          fruits.onChange(e); // react hook form onChange
          console.log("Here would go the my onChange"); // my onChange
        }}
        {...register('fruits')}
        onBlur={fruits.onBlur}
        ref={fruits.ref}
      >
        <option value="1Banana">Banana</option>
        <option value="1Kiwi">Kiwi</option>
        <option value="1Mango">Mango</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a useState hook it's working link so:

`e.target.value` is the selected value of your dropdown menu. To change your title dynamically you have to use a hook to serenader your component when the state changes.

See bellow:

```html
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const { register, watch } = useForm();
  // const myValue = watch("fruits", "default");
  const [myVal, setMyVal] = React.useState('Default')

  const fruits = register("fruits");


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{myVal}</h1>
      <select
        onChange={(e) => {
          fruits.onChange(e);
          setMyVal(e.target.value); // react hook form onChange
          console.log("Here would go the my onChange"); // my onChange
        }}
        onBlur={fruits.onBlur}
        ref={fruits.ref}
      >
        <option value="1Banana">Banana</option>
        <option value="1Kiwi">Kiwi</option>
        <option value="1Mango">Mango</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Still, I am trying to do it with `watch()` since the selected value of the <select> element should get saved within the form and used in the `handleSubmit` of the react-hook-form. The answer of @Sergiu Paraschiv is the right one.

Comment: Yep just saw the other response that looks better for your problem!